# How do I fix this code where a collection is being mutated while being enumerated?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I correct the following code? It says I'm changing a collection while it's being enumerated through, but I can't pin down exactly why this is happening.

**Fatal Exception: NSGenericException
*** Collection <ZBarSymbolSet: 0x28062ab80> was mutated while being enumerated.**

**[ZBarReaderView didTrackSymbols:]**

```
- (void) didTrackSymbols: (ZBarSymbolSet*) syms
{
    if(!tracksSymbols)
        return;

    int n = syms.count;
    assert(n);
    if(!n)
        return;

    ZBarSymbol *sym = nil;
    for(ZBarSymbol *s in syms)
        if(!sym || s.type == ZBAR_QRCODE || s.quality > sym.quality)
            sym = s;
    assert(sym);
    if(!sym)
        return;

    [self updateTracking: tracking
          withSymbol: sym];
}
```

My only thought is that maybe `syms` is getting changed somewhere outside of this somehow?

Comment: do you know where the exception is thrown from?

Comment: The only details the crash log on Firebase says is that it's in `[ZBarReaderView didTrackSymbols:]`, which is the function I posted.

Comment: Do not tag C for Objective-C questions.

Comment: Apologies. The ZBar code elsewhere in the project is a mix of C and Objective-C, so I just did it without thinking.

Comment: I have actually found reports of the same bug from 2014. Could I please ask you why are you still using ZBar? iOS has had native reading of barcodes for at least 9 years.

Comment: @Sulthan I am only using it to scan comic book and magazine barcodes that have +2 and +5 EAN extensions. The built-in iOS scanner doesn't allow that type of scanning. I use the iOS scanner for all other types of scans.

Comment: The only idea I have is that the enumeration is done simultaneously with another thread that is modifying the collection.

Comment: One possibility is multi-thread access, though that would be a bit as likely to create more erratic errors (since you could get data corruption that way). I'd first double check how `[ZBarSymbol type]` and `[ZBarSymbol quality]` are implemented and make sure they don't have side-effects that could influence `syms`. One way you could exclude that possibility (and to get some insurance against other threads) is to call `for(ZBarSymbol *s in [syms copy])` to make a copy before enumerating.